# how to fit exponential curve such as a*b^t in r?

Tags: r

```
input <- "    
  t    y    
 1  5.3    
 2  7.2    
 3  9.6    
 4 12.9    
 5 17.1    
 6 23.2"         
dat<-read.table(textConnection(input),header=TRUE,sep="")    
t<-dat[,1]    
y<-dat[,2]
```

`y=3.975*(1.341^t)` is the resule of fit,how can i use `nls` function to get it?
maybe the problem is how to express the formula?

```
nls(y~(a*b^t))
Error in getInitial.default(func, data, mCall = as.list(match.call(func,  : 
no 'getInitial' method found for "function" objects
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
nls(y~(a*b^t),start=c(a=4,b=1))
```

`nls` needs a good starting point for each parameter

Comment: By your knowledge/experience. Base on the equation, both should be larger than zero. Is always a value for t=1 available? If yes use this for value for `a`. Take a second one and calculate (not fit) b, and use that. Non linear fits may fail (or find just a local minimum) if they start at the wrong place. By the way a=10, b=10 worked too.

Comment: And consider fitting log(texp) instead of t for a simple strategy to avoid failure in getInitial.